# On click load modal window with ajax gif

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, loading, gif

I've got this code, but it's not working. Please can someone help me out? Would very much appreciate it.

```
$("#Picture1, #Picture2, #Picture3, #Picture4").click(function() {
$('#loading').hide().ajaxStart(function() {
  $(this).show();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
$("#popupContainer").fadeIn(250);
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()` functions to the `document`, so that it will watch for AJAX events anywhere on the page.

The way you have it coded now, you are only watching for AJAX events within the element with the ID of `loading`, which I believe is your busy wait indicator, right?

Try this:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#loading').show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
});
```

Now in your click handler, whenever you perform an AJAX operation the busy wait (read: loading element) will show when it starts and hide when the AJAX operation ends.

```
$("#Picture1, #Picture2, #Picture3, #Picture4").click(function() {
    // Do AJAX operation here
});
```

UPDATE:

Since you do not want to show a loading message when AJAX operations occur, but rather when the button is clicked and then hide the message when the popup is done fading in, then I recommend the [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/).

Comment: What would I put where you said // Do AJAX operation here?

Comment: Are you not making AJAX calls in your code? Are you trying to show a loading image while the popup container fades in for 250 milliseconds?

Comment: Im trying to make a pop up appear but load with a gif on click

Comment: You should look into the jQuery BlockUI Plugin, I have updated my answer to include a link to this plugin.